# Replace user photo on Windows 7 lock screen with a custom image

Tags: windows-7, images

I want to replace the photo on the lock screen with my own custom image. I can't find the folder where those images are stored. Does anyone know where they're located in the Window 7 Pro file structure?

[image: screenshot of lockscreen]

Comment: @n8te -- Huh? There's no upvote button nor can I mark your answer as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The picture above your username on the lockscreen in Windows 7 is your user profile pic. To change it do the following:

- Open **Control Panel**
- Go to **User Accounts**
- Under **Make changes to your account** go to **Change your picture**
- Underneath all the stock photos select **Browse for more pictures...**
- Navigate to the folder path of the pic of your choosing and select it

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy solution. That is a user profile picture. There is not defined structure, and it only checks the dialog where you can select a custom image. To do this, open the start menu by pressing the `⊞` key, then click `Change Your Picture` and select one of the built in ones, or browse for pictures inside your local storage by clicking `Browse for more pictures`

I hope this helps

Thanks,

yg.swagness